# Using an apache2 instance already hosting websites as a reverse proxy to force HTTPS

Tags: apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

I'm running an Apache2 instance on Debian 10 and I have an application that only supports HTTP and runs on port 53842 (although that can be changed), however, when I try to connect to it, Firefox force redirects to HTTPS and throws an error (Chromium works on HTTP though.) As everyone who would possibly use it is using Firefox, I thought of using my already running Apache2 web server as a reverse proxy to it, however, I am unsure as to how to do this. I googled around and added this to the end of my apache2.conf file, however, this did not work as Apache throws a not found error.

[image: The config]

Is there any way to keep all of my websites running on this same apache server and also use it as a reverse proxy to a specific application?

Comment: `Order`, `Allow`, `SSLProxyEngine on`, `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` etc. should be on separate lines and it's better to put your proxy configuration in a separate configuration file (depending on your particular distribution). Did you enable `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` in Apache and does Apache listen on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http are both enabled. I'll put Order, allow, etc on separate lines too. Apache also listens on 127.0.0.1 (I think), however, I am not sure how to check that.

Comment: Oh whoops, the formatting got a bit messed up, they are on separate lines. I'll try to fix it in the original post.

Comment: Disregard my comment about Apache listening on 127.0.0.1. Your *application* should be listening on that IP address and port 53842..

Comment: Possibly the application also needs to be configured for being accessed from a subdirectory of the main site (`"/gokapi"`).

Comment: Ah, The application is listening for sure on 127.0.0.1 and port 53842 (as I can access it from there using Lynx) however I am not sure about it being accessed from a subdirectory. The developer of it recommended using a reverse proxy himself so I would imagine that it would support that though.

Comment: I have moved the program to another server and ran it on port 80 instead just to rule out any issues caused by it being on the same server and on a strange port, and it still doesn't work after setting the settings in apache2.conf to the new server ip and port.